# How and when to use Guid?

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm going through kinect tutorials with C#, and there is an interface named IBufferByteAccess is used for reading writing an IBuffer, the code looks like this:

```
    [Guid("905a0fef-bc53-11df-8c49-001e4fc686da"),
             InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IBufferByteAccess
    {
        unsafe void Buffer(out byte* pByte);
    }
```

I just cannot understand the use of 'Guid'. Error occurs if I comment out the Guid. I found an explanation saying it is a global identification. But how do I know I should use it when it is needed? And where to find the value?

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, [GuidAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Supplies an explicit `System.Guid` when an automatic GUID is undesirable.

There is a related [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718967/is-system-runtime-interopservices-guidattribute-used-for-anything-except-com-int) with an answer, which may help you:

> A type in .NET always has a Guid whether you use the attribute or not. Available through the Type.GUID property. The CLR auto-generates one from the type definition, ensuring that identical types have identical Guids regardless on what machine it gets generated. Note that this is very different behavior from the usual way a Guid is generated.
>
> You only use the `[Guid]` attribute if you want to override the auto-generated guid. Which is only useful in COM interop scenarios to get a declaration to match an existing COM interface or coclass.